# Is it possible to strengthen/tighten the LES (lower esophageal sphincter)?

Tags: stomach, acidic, esophagus, gerd-acid-reflux, lower-esoph-sphincter-les

To my knowledge, in relation to GERD, certain things you aren't supposed to have include coffee, tea, spicy foods, citrus foods, and chocolate because they relax the (LES) "lower esophageal sphincter."

Is there an opposite to this?  Are there any foods/drinks/actions/other which strengthen or tighten the LES?  If there are, how do they work?

I've done some searching and found a lot of potential answers, but they are mostly hearsay and don't come with much logical explanation.  That being said, here's what I've found as "advice":

[?L-GLUTAMINE strengthens muscles, including LES?](http://www.healthboards.com/boards/acid-reflux-gerd/552661-anything-natural-will-tighten-les.html)

[?Deep breaths stretch/strengthen abdominal muscles, including LES?](http://healgerd.com/2011/12/17/strengthening-the-les/)

I also found something on Health Tap that briefly said nothing but surgery works.  I believe that surgery works, less so that it's the only solution (though it may be the only one found).